# Created a second page in Eclipse for Android App, but not working

Tags: java, android, mobile

I created the first default Hello World Page in Android, but I placed a button there to move the screen to second window (which I created). But When I am clicking on first button, it moves me to a blank page.

Actually my second page has a button (showing Second page), but why android in not showing it?
Am I mistaking something?

MainActivity.java file content is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Second.java content is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Here are the application screenshots:

1. http://pbrd.co/YRNZvw
2. http://pbrd.co/YRNNN5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are saying your layout file for `activity_second.xml` has a button on it. When you switch to `Graphic Layout` in eclipse, do you see the button? You must see it there first. If it's not, it will usually tell you why. Also you must `setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);` in `onCreate` of the Second class.

EDIT:

To save yourself some trouble next time, since you are using eclipse, to add a new activity to a project do the following:

```
click new -> android -> Android Activity
```

And from there add a name and an optional parent activity. That should do all the basic wirings for you, and you would not have this problem.

Comment: you have to define a layout in your layout file and set it as a content for your second activity, the error is because you don have a xml file defined in that name inside your layout folder

Comment: After you type `R.layout.` in eclipse, you should press `control-space` to see a list of valid ids and just pick the correct one. Whatever you name your xml should certainly show up there.

Comment: "click new -> android -> Android Activity"

But my eclipse don't have such option PFA:http://pbrd.co/YRV3sf

Comment: After clicking `new` you may have to click `other` to get to `android`. `other` is at the very bottom sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the setContentView in the OnCreate of your second activity.

Should be something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Comment: @user1547766 -- That error is just saying you are using the wrong layout id.  Use the id you entered in the layout editor.

Comment: I am getting error: http://pbrd.co/YRSRRz, while I have set the relative layou ID set http://pbrd.co/YRT0o0

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(R.your_layout_id);
```

Call this in `onCreate` method of second `Activity`

or replace your onCreate function like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    button.setText("Click Me");
    setContentView(button);


}
```

Comment: check you are importing the Correct R file

Comment: there are only 2 imports in Second.java: import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: R file should be com.yourpackge.projectname.R it should not be android.R

Comment: Still I am getting error: http://pbrd.co/YRSRRz, while I have set the relative layou ID set http://pbrd.co/YRT0o0